# Trying to get rid of Ubuntu option in device startup menu - windows 10 lenovo desktop

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot

[image: Startup device menu option]

I am trying to get rid the the Ubuntu option in my startup device menu, I already deleted the Ubuntu OS and deleted the partition and merged it back to the Windows partition. I tried getting rid of the option in the startup device  menu, by using the bcdedit cmd and deleting it from there, but I don't see the Ubuntu OS listed in any partition there. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you removed GRUB?

Comment: Am not sure, i just deleted the ubuntu os in my partition and merge that partition back to the windows drive

Comment: That menu looks to be from the BIOS, rather than a HDD. Might want to check the BIOS.

Comment: what should i do in the bios? to remove the ubuntu options?

Comment: BIOS (UEFI) firmware usually has options to delete boot entries, just select "Enter Setup", then Boot options, there you should be able to delete boot entries.